# Node no longer exists using SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

Trying to cache an xml file using the build in wordpress function called get_transient but I'm getting a php error:

**unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Node no longer exists**

```
//check the db to see if it exists ( get_transient is a WordPress function)
if (false === ($response_xml = get_transient('stats_from_xml_feed'))){

 $request_url = "http://example.com/feed.xml";
 $request_url = urlencode($request_url);
 $response_xml = @simplexml_load_file($request_url);
 //kill request if connection problem
 if ($response_xml === FALSE){
 exit ('could not connect');
 } else {
     // here we throw it into the WordPress temp DB using set_transient for 12 hours
   set_transient('stats_from_xml_feed', $response_xml, 60*60*12);

 //some output
$res =  $response_xml;
$name = $res->name;

echo $name;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node no longer exists error with Zend_Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084256/node-no-longer-exists-error-with-zend-session)

Comment: Possible duplicate of a bazillion other questions as well... Please do search before asking a question. http://tinyurl.com/4lr4nef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$response_xml` is an instance of the `SimpleXMLElement` class.  A `SimpleXMLElement` should not be (un)serialized, because it wraps a [resource](http://php.net/types.resource) within the object.

Instead, serialize something which will happily survive the process; the raw response from the feed, all/part of the XML after loading it into the `SimpleXMLElement` and using the [`asXML()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.asxml) method, an array of the (likely string) values you want, or some other structure which is okay to be serialized.

One thing to consider is that you will see the *`unserialize(): Node no longer exists`* warning in "older" (to use the term loosely) versions of PHP. As of PHP 5.3.2, the behaviour changed to throw an `Exception` with the message *`Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed`*.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't (can't?) `serialize` and `unserialize` the SimpleXML object.  It's XML, which is a serialization format to begin with.  This ain't Inception here!

Call the [`asXML`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method to get the actual XML, then store that instead.

Comment: Why then is it possible to serialize DomDocument?

Comment: @Gildas, try serializing your DOMDocument, or even a DOMNodeList.  You'll find that while they *serialize* without error, they're entirely empty.  Again, XML *is* a serialization format.