# Parse a json(?) string using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, json

I have a string, more specifically, this one:

```
a:16:{s:9:"pseudonym";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:14:"parallel_title";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:9:"title_var";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:6:"series";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:9:"vol_title";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:9:"reference";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:10:"bound_with";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:15:"general_remarks";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:6:"copies";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}s:11:"remarks_BPH";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:3:"ICN";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":1:{i:0;s:4:"neen";}s:10:"provenance";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:7:"binding";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:10:"size_hxwxd";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}s:6:"BookID";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":1:{i:0;s:4:"6271";}s:5:"repro";O:16:"SimpleXMLElement":0:{}}
```

Is it possible to parse this string somehow? I need to display the keys and values in a list. I tried to use `json_decode` but it doesn't return anything, even with the second parameter set to `true`:

```
json_decode($string,true);
```

Comment: I am not sure what stopped you from doing a 2 second google search...

Comment: That doesn't look like Json to me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not JSON, it's serialized PHP. Use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: Yes, that might be the trick however i tried to use the unserialize function, it i got several php errors: Warning: unserialize(): Node no longer exists in ...file.php on line 39 and it keeps repeating.

Comment: @passatgt It is not a trick. It is serialized PHP. And a SimpleXmlElement cannot be unserialized, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5264628/1229260

Comment: @passatgt Was my answer helpful? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

It's serialize object

Read more on [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)